# How can a supplicant offer "the first wounds, the first pains and the first bloodshed"?

Tags: catholicism

Having just encountered this question [Can a devil use one prayer to prevent us from praying a different one](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/54345/can-a-devil-use-one-prayer-to-prevent-us-from-praying-different-one)

I encountered [The Twelve Year Prayer of S. Bridget of Sweden](https://sites.google.com/site/catholictopics/spirituality-and-prayer/the-twelve-year-prayer-of-s-bridget-of-sweden)

The first verse of the prayer is as follows: -

> Our Father.  Hail Mary. Eternal Father, through Mary’s unblemished
>   hands and the Divine Heart of Jesus, I offer to Thee the first wounds,
>   the first pains and the first bloodshed, as atonement for my & all of
>   humanity’s sins of youth, as protection against the first mortal sin,
>   especially among my relatives.

I am confused, how is a supplicant able to 'offer' these things? Surely they belong to God in the first place?

Comment: It's similar in the Divine Mercy Chaplet prayer "I offer you the Body and Blood Soul and Divinity of your Dearly Beloved Son, Our Lord Jesus Christ, in atonement for our sins and those of the whole world".  I'd bet that somewhere St. Faustina covers this - I wish I had her books!